# Get a country code from 'navigator.languages' in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, locale

I'm using `navigator.languages` to detect the browser's **language** & **country** code in the form of `en-US`.

If I set my browser language to English then I get `en-US` but if I set it to Japanese it only returns `ja`, without the country code `JP`. Obviously Japanese is only spoken in Japan in the whole world so they must have omitted it. The same goes for Korean as I get `ko` instead of `ko_KR`.

But I need both information because the Facebook SDK script I'm loading requires it in the format of `ll_cc` as below:

`https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js`
`https://connect.facebook.net/ja_JP/sdk.js`

According to the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#language), Putting `ja_JP` in the script address is the only way to achieve the change in display language.

I would like to change the display language based on users' browser language settings. (e.g., Japanese, Korean etc)

So how should I go about getting the country code `JP` from browser?

I was thinking about creating a table to match the language to country code in the case of one-to-one, but I was curious to see if there is better way to approach this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: how is this `broswer.languages` defined? I certainly don't have such a property in my broswer

Comment: oh, I didn't notice the typo (I just copy pasted without thinking) ... but I don't have browser.languages in my browser either - is this some sort of browser web extension you're talking about?

Comment: My bad. It is `navigator.languages`. I updated the title as well. Thanks

Comment: You can't without user permission. You can try to derive it from IP with geocoding but it's not super reliable. If the user will give you permission you can use html5 geolocation API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Comment: @Matt For the most part that may work. But in some cases the geolocation is not necessarily the same as the users' browser language country code.

Comment: Agreed. Consequently, the language country code is not necessarily the country they are in.

Answer (score 0):

What `navigator.language`, as specified in [BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), gets you is the International Standards Organization's [ISO 639-1](https://www.iso.org/standard/22109.html) language code, which is primarily a 2-letter code. (like `en` for English and `jp` for Japanese)

There is a exception for languages with dialects, versions or variations of a language which require another specified language code. (Like `en-us` for the United States's version of English, which differs from for example the United Kingdom's version of English (`en-gb`).

What you had was a confusing overlap between the combination of a language code and a combination of a language and country code.

In order for you to meet the `language-country` code format, you will need to reference [ISO-639-1](https://www.iso.org/standard/22109.html) and [ISO-3166](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html) or a website the conveniently combines the two, [here](https://www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml) for example.

Here is some code I wrote that should work. *fingers-crossed* This is my first time writing a answer so please let me know if I did anything wrong.

```js
/// Note the l2.io and jQuery script tag


/// From Xposedbones (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999265/get-country-code-using-javascript)
var country_code = null;
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/' + userip, function(data){
  country_code = data.country;
  console.log(country_code)
    
  /// Modified From MDN Web Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)
  var language_code = navigator.language.split("-")[0] /// There is probably a better way for this

  /// Combine country and language
  const combined = `${language_code}-${country_code}`
  alert(combined)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
```

Comment: Using the IP address to deduct the country code may work for the most part. However, it does not account for the browser's language settings, which is the key information that I'm interested in. For instance, my browser thinks my one & only language is `en_US` and I want it to stay that way, even though I'm not geographically located in the United States.